# prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=\binom{2n+1}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics

How to prove this formula? I tried Catalan numbers but failed.
I am interested in a solution, not a clue.

Comment: This is a special case of the Rothe-Hagen identity. Please see the second section of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) and improve your question by adding some context/attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Write $C_n=\frac1{k+1}\binom{2k}k$. Then your sum is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series for $C(x)D(x)$ where $C(x)=\sum C_n x^n
=(1-\sqrt{1-4x})/(2x)$ and $D(x)=\sum\binom{2n}n x^n=1/\sqrt{1-4x}$.
So $$C(x)D(x)=\frac{1}{2x}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}-1\right)$$
etc.

Comment: No doubt this is correct and efficient, but would you mind waiting for the OP to improve his question?